# File copy via SHFileOperation() - basic flags to use

Tags: delphi, winapi

I found some code for copying files using `SHFileOperation()` but I am confused by all the flags available in the [SHFILEOPSTRUCT structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759795.aspx).

Here's what I am doing. I have a recursive process that fills a `TStringList` with all the files according to my set-mask. I step through that `TStringList` and pass complete paths for `FileFrom` and `FileTo`.

```
F.Wnd:=frmMain.Handle;
F.wFunc:=FO_COPY;
F.pFrom:=PChar(FileFrom+#0);
F.pTo:=PChar(FileTo+#0);
Err:=ShFileOperation(F);
```

Here's what I want to do.

1. If a file is larger than 10mb then I want to show Windows' Progress Dialog, if smaller then show nothing.
2. Be able to abort the copy process **without** needing to click the "X" in the Progress Dialog as it may not be displayed when copying a lot of smaller files. I have a "Cancel" button and a boolean "CancelClicked", but I can't see how to get an "Abort" back from the `SHFileOperation()`.

I know I could just pass the entire folder to `SHFileOperation()` and have it operate recursively, but I need to process other stuff on each file, so stepping though the `TStringList` is how I need to do it, but I am open to suggestions.

Finally the questions:

What `fFlags` do I need set for the under-10mb size?

What `fFlags` do I need set for the over-10mb size?

```
if ThisFileSize < 10000000 then
  F.fFlags:=F.fFlags or ... else
  F.fFlags:= ...;
```

---

This code does NOT copy, but the commented line DOES copy.

```
lpCopyProgress:=@MyCopyProgressCallback;
Err:=0;
StopCopy:=False;
if not CopyFileEx(PChar(FileFrom),PChar(FileTo),lpCopyProgress,nil,@StopCopy,0) then
//          if not CopyFile(PChar(FileFrom),PChar(FileTo),False) then
begin
  Err:=GetLastError;
  if Err = ERROR_REQUEST_ABORTED then
    Break;
end;
```

Comment: Use FOF_SILENT for small files, all flags are explained in the documentation.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You've proved you know where the documentation is. Have you read it? You saw the part about `fof_Silent `, right? Did you try it? What further question do you have? Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy: Thanks, I am wondering if I should have more than just that, like "FOF_FILESONLY" and/or "FOF_NOCONFIRMATION" and/or "FOF_NOERRORUI" and/or...etc. Just what is assumed (default) with no Flags and what I need to define.

Answer (score 4):

When using `SHFileOperation()`, you can use the `FOF_SILENT` flag to prevent the standard Progress Dialog from being shown.

However, there is no option available to programmably abort `SHFileOperation()` once it starts running.  For that, use [`CopyFileEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363852.aspx) or [`CopyFile2()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh449404.aspx) instead.

Both functions allow you to abort a copy in two different ways:

- they both accept a pointer to a `BOOL` variable as input.  If your code sets that `BOOL` variable to `TRUE` while the function is running, the copy is aborted.
- they both accept a pointer to a callback function for progress reporting.  The callback is called during various stages of the copy. If the callback returns a value of `CANCEL` or `STOP`, the copy is aborted (and in the case of `CANCEL`, the target file is deleted, whereas `STOP` allows the file to be resumed at a later time).

Either way, both functions do not display Windows' own Progress Dialog automatically, but you can [display it manually](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9298/Using-Windows-Explorer-Progress-Dialog-In-Your-App) using the [`IProgressDialog`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775248.aspx) interface. Or, you can display your own custom dialog instead.

It is not a good user experience to show/hide a progress dialog on each individual file when processing multiple files.  It is wasted overhead on the OS to create and destroy the dialogs.  The potential flickering is not fun for the user to look at visually.  You should display the dialog once when it is needed, and then keep it visible and updated until the last file is done.

Try something like this:

```
var
  // this is redundant since IProgressDialog has its own
  // Cancel button, this is just an example to demonstrate
  // cancellation in code...
  CancelClicked: BOOL = FALSE;

function MyCopyProgressCallback(TotalFileSize, TotalBytesTransferred, StreamSize, StreamBytesTransferred: LARGE_INTEGER; dwStreamNumber: DWORD; dwCallbackReason: DWORD; hSourceFile, hDestinationFile: THandle; lpData: Pointer): DWORD; stdcall;
var
  msg: WideString;
begin
  msg := WideFormat('Transferred %d of %d bytes', [TotalBytesTransferred.QuadPart, TotalFileSize.QuadPart]);
  IProgressDialog(lpData).SetLine(2, PWideChar(msg), False, PPointer(nil)^);
  if IProgressDialog(lpData).HasUserCancelled then
    Result := PROGRESS_CANCEL
  else
    Result := PROGRESS_CONTINUE;
end;

...

var
  FileFrom: string;
  FileTo: string;
  I: Integer;
  ProgressDialog: IProgressDialog;
begin
  ...

  CancelClicked := FALSE;

  OleCheck(CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ProgressDialog, nil, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IProgressDialog, ProgressDialog));
  try
    ProgressDialog.SetTitle('Processing files');
    ProgressDialog.SetCancelMsg('Canceling, please wait...', PPointer(nil)^);
    ProgressDialog.SetProgress(0, TheStringList.Count);
    ProgressDialog.StartProgressDialog(frmMain.Handle, nil, PROGDLG_MODAL or PROGDLG_AUTOTIME or PROGDLG_NOMINIMIZE, PPointer(nil)^);
    ProgressDialog.Timer(PDTIMER_RESET, PPointer(nil)^);

    for I := 0 to TheStringList.Count-1 do
    begin
      FileFrom := ...;
      FileTo := ...;

      ProgressDialog.SetLine(1, PWideChar(WideString(FileFrom)), True, PPointer(nil)^);
      ProgressDialog.SetLine(2, '', False, PPointer(nil)^);
      if ProgressDialog.HasUserCancelled then
        Break;

      ...

      if not CopyFileEx(PChar(FileFrom), PChar(FileTo), @MyCopyProgressCallback, Pointer(ProgressDialog), @CancelClicked, 0) then
      begin
        if GetLastError = ERROR_REQUEST_ABORTED then
          Break;

        // something else happened during the copy, so
        // you can decide whether to stop the loop here
        // or just move on to the next file...
      end;

      ...

      ProgressDialog.SetProgress(I+1, TheStringList.Count);
    end;
  finally
    ProgressDialog.StopProgressDialog;
    ProgressDialog := nil;
  end;

  ...

end;
```

Alternatively, you can use the [`IFileOperation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775771.aspx) interface instead.  This allows you to:

- queue up all of the file paths ahead of time using its [`CopyItem()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775761.aspx) and [`CopyItems()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775763.aspx) methods.
- perform all of the queued copies at one time using its [`PerformOperations()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775780.aspx) method.
- implement the [`IFileOperationProgressSink`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775722.aspx) interface and [`Advise()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775755.aspx) it to receive progress updates.  This includes the option to perform your own operations before ([`PreCopyItem()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775737.aspx)) and after ([`PostCopyItem()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775726.aspx)) each individual file is copied.  Any error you return from an `IFileOperationProgressSink` method will abort the entire copy sequence.
- let it display the standard Windows Progress Dialog automatically. It will delay displaying the dialog until the copy sequence takes more than a few seconds to run.  If you copy a bunch of little files quickly, there is no need for it to display the dialog, but once a noticable delay occurs, the dialog will be displayed for the current and subsequent files until the sequence is finished. If you want to customize the behavior, you can implement the [`IOperationsProgressDialog`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775368.aspx) interface and pass it to the [`IFileOperation::SetProgressDialog()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775803.aspx) method.

Comment: Thanks, but that did not compile as shown so a quick search suggested that "lpCopyProgress: should be "@lpCopyProgress" and then it compiled. But, it is not copying and LastError = 0.

Comment: No, it should not be `@lpCopyProgress`.  I have updated the example in my answer.  Also, it is not possible for `GetLastError()` to return 0 if `CopyFileEx()` fails, which implies that your code is not doing error handling correctly.

Comment: I changed to the adjusted source but still it does not copy. If I use this ` if not CopyFile(PChar(FileFrom),PChar(FileTo),False) then` it copies the files. I will add actual code to the OP above.

Comment: What does `GetLastError()` return when `CopyFileEx()`? In the code showed, it *CANNOT* return 0.

Comment: It can and it does return Zero even though it does NOT copy anything. But moot as I figured it out and it is working, but your code above needs tweaking.

Comment: If `CopyFileEx()` fails, it itself returns 0, but `GetLastError()` **does not** return 0 afterwards, *UNLESS* you do something to cause the error code to be reset after `CopyFileEx()` exits and before `GetLastError()` is called.  But if you call `GetLastError()` **immediately** after `CopyFileEx()` returns 0, `GetLastError()` **cannot** return 0.